# Printing pdf from iframe not working in mozilla

Tags: firefox, iframe, printing

I want to print pdf inside an iframe. It works perfectly in chrome, but in mozilla, it's not working at all. do you guys have any solution for this?

```
<iframe id="pdftoprint" style="display:none; position:absolute;" src="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf"></iframe>

<div class="buttonimage"><img src="print.png" onclick="print_elem('pdftoprint')"></div>
function print_elem(elem_name)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elem_name);
    elem.contentWindow.focus();
    elem.contentWindow.print(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Firefox will not let you access the element if the URL of the page does not start with www. Try adding this script to the top of your page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ( location.host.toLowerCase().substring(0,3) != "www" )
        {
            location.href = location.href.replace( /\/\//, "//www." );
        }
    </script>
```

This will redirect the user to a the same URL but adds www. to the start of it. Hope this helps, it worked for me.